# Connect to Database on Same Network But Different Machine From Mysql Workbench

Tags: mysql, ssh

I've got a web server/database server running on my local network. I've set the static ip to 192.168.1.210. I've installed mysql on the server, set the my.cnf bind-address to the static ip.

I am trying to use mysql workbench on my dev machine to connect to that database (on a different machine but in the same local network) so that I can manage the database through a gui rather than having to manage it through SSH.

I've tried setting up a new connection using the static ip as the host, default 3306 port. I've tried setting up the connection over standard TCP/IP and also TCP/IP through SSH in workbench and I can't connect.

I know networking to the server is working because I can SSH into it just fine. I am trying to use root as the username from workbench but I never get to the point where it asks me for a password.

Is there a guide somewhere out there? I can't seem to find any good resources.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There were a few things I had to do.

First log into mysql using root from local machine (the server, but I used ssh) and add a new remote user.

```
mysql -u root -p
```

It will prompt for a password. Then create a new user that has access from anywhere.

```
CREATE USER 'username'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'username'@'%';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

Then quit and restart mysql.

```
sudo service mysql restart
```

I also had to edit the /etc/mysql/my.cnf and comment out the bind-address line which is normally set to 127.0.0.1 which means that access is only allows from local machine...basically.

Last but not least, I am using the basic ubuntu server firewall so I had to allow access to port 3306 (default mysql port which can also be changed in my.cnf).

```
sudo ufw allow 3306
```

Then check the status to make sure it worked.

```
sudo ufw status
```

You'll see port 3306 in the list.

You can test access to the database using your new username with the following command.

```
mysql -h <server ip address> -u username -p
```

It will prompt for your new password and should connect properly.

I had gotten stuck on the firewall portion. It never crossed my mind to check for that.